# How to fix this 'Lambdas should be replaced with method references' sonar issue in java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

```
public static Set<NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper> create(final Set<NurseViewPrescriptionDTO> nurseViewPrescriptionDTOs) {
  return nurseViewPrescriptionDTOs.stream()
      .map(new Function<NurseViewPrescriptionDTO, NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper>() {
        @Override
        public NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper apply(NurseViewPrescriptionDTO input) {
          return new NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper(input);
        }
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

I convert above code to java 8 lamda function as below.

```
public static Set<NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper> create(final Set<NurseViewPrescriptionDTO> nurseViewPrescriptionDTOs) {
  return nurseViewPrescriptionDTOs.stream()
      .map(input -> new NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper(input))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Now, I am receiving sonar issue, like `Lambdas should be replaced with method references` , to  '->' this symbol. How i can fix this issue ?

Comment: simple way is defining a method that get a `NurseViewPrescriptionDTO` as an argument and convert it to `NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper`. like `private NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper convert(NurseViewPrescriptionDTO d){return new NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper(d);}` then use in `... map(YOURCALSS::convert) ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your lambda,

```
.map(input -> new NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper(input))
```

can be replaced by

```
.map(NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper::new)
```

That syntax is a method reference syntax. In the case of `NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper::new` is a special method reference that refers to a constructor

Answer (score 3):

Given you have an appropriate constructor, you could simply replace your statement as:

```
public static Set<NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper> create(final Set<NurseViewPrescriptionDTO> nurseViewPrescriptionDTOs) {
    return nurseViewPrescriptionDTOs.stream()
                            .map(NurseViewPrescriptionWrapper::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```